# How to set text bidirectional in html web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, utf-8

I want to be set a text direction automatic on the HTML web page. I fond some solutions but its not working properly. I used `dir=" auto"` for HTML page in this way `<html lang="en" dir="auto">`. but it didn't seem to be working(see left side image). and if I used it for div elements that contain other elements that I have to set bidirectional text but it shows all text right to left (see right side image). Currently, I have added Arabic and English language. I want to set an Arabic language text from right to left automatically. Is there any proper solution for this issue?
Please see the below images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `rtl`. `<div dir="rtl">`

Comment: Hello Shree, is there any other way to do it automatically instead of specifying dir attribute at the element level?

Comment: You can add / remove class based upon content via  jquery. `.content {
    direction: rtl;
}`

Comment: OK thanx. But what will be the solution if the language text direction will be unknown?

Comment: You can use 3rd party library to detect language from given input . I use this one and it's cool `https://github.com/wooorm/franc`

Comment: I think you should put the `dir="auto"` at every message. The browser try to find the direction, but after he find Arabic, it will use `rtl` for the rest of the `<div>`. If every message has own `auto`, the browser will check the direction in every message

Answer (score 1):

if you had the info about the locale of each message,
you could add it to markup,for example:

```
<div class="message" data-locale="ar" >
```

and in css you can then do sth like:

```
.message {
  direction: ltr; /* default btw */
}
.message[data-locale="ar"]{
  direction: rtl; 
}
```